# is there an attribute (gcc, clang, other compiler) that says a function always terminates normally?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Consider the following C program:

```
double local_array[10];
/* local computations */
f(); // f() cannot modify the local_array since the local_array has not escaped
local_array[i] += 5.0;
```

If `f()` is known to return normally, then one can move `local_array[i] += 5.0;` before the call, perhaps for efficiency (one can intermingle the load - float add - store sequence with preceding computations).

However, if `f()` is not known to return normally, this is likely to be illegal with respect to the standard. Indeed, if `f()` prints an error message and exits, it would be dangerous to precede it with an access to `local_array[i]` that could fail (bad pointer due to an incorrect value of `i`). We have no way to know whether `p` points to valid, writable memory. Perhaps `f()` performs a check that excludes invalid values of `p`.

So my question: is there a way to tell the compiler (perhaps gcc or clang) that a function always returns normally?

There is a `nothrow` attribute but it seems slightly different.

Such an attribute would be the "dual" of `noreturn`, which means that a function never returns.

If you wonder what this is about: PostgresSQL [bug #616180](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=616180) was about old versions of `gcc` assuming they could make similar moves of a trapping instruction in front of a function call that terminated program execution (due to the detection of an internal error). I consider that what `gcc` was doing was incorrect… But then how would it be possible to tell it that it is allowed to perform such an optimization?

Comment: `[[pure]]` is suggested, but not currently voted in. `[[gnu:pure]]` works for gcc. it's sligtly different, but is probably the best you can get

Comment: What does it mean to "return normally"?

Comment: Does the `f()` potentially modify `p`? The question is somewhat unclear. You should [edit] and add some (even pseudo) code.

Comment: "If f() is known to return normally, then one can move *p += 5.0; before the call," Without providing more details about `f` and `p` that is a questionable statement. What if `f` is responsible to assign a valid address to `p`? Or what it `p` points to some hardware register where write accesses from within `f` and the calling function would be executed in reverse order then? Returning from `f` is only one details here.

Comment: And how exactly does your program precede after some function has called `exit()`? That doesn't make any sense unless this is some sort of multi-process project. Generally speaking, it is bad practice to have general library code print error messages and close down shop - it should just return an error status to the caller and let the caller deal with the error as it pleases.

Comment: `pure` is not usable for functions returning `void`, and has a different meaning.

Comment: "Generally speaking, it is bad practice to have general library code print error messages and close down shop - it should just return an error status to the caller and let the caller deal with the error as it pleases" → That's what `abort()` and other standard library functions do, and what is usually done when encountering an abnormal condition inside the data structures of the application (memory corruption, invariant violation etc.). This is similar to "panic" in Rust. I agree that panicking should not be used when a "normal" error condition (e.g. "file does not open") is encountered.

Comment: "Or what it p points to some hardware register where write accesses from within f and the calling function would be executed in reverse order then?" → then `*p` should be declared as `volatile`, shouldn't it? Any access that needs to be externally observable (hardware registers) needs to be `volatile`.

Comment: @KamilCuk Well, "returns" as opposed to "calls `exit()` and makes the program terminate" or "calls longjmp()".

Comment: Re “note that f() cannot modify p”: That is inadequate. To be sure that `f()` commutes with `*p += 5.0`, `f` must also not read `*p` or read `p` and save that value. How do you expect the compiler to know `f` does not read or modify `p`? Is it because `p` has block scope and its address is never taken or is visibly not available to `f`?

Comment: The compiler must also know that `p` does not point to anything that `f` uses. That seems like a stretch.

Comment: The example is clearer now: `p` points into a local array that does not escape its scope (its addressed is neither passed to `f` nor stored into a global variable). There is no way that `f` can change `p` or what it points to.

Comment: `If you wonder what this is about` I do not see how is the issue there related to your question. Your question is great - "does there exist a function attribute that would tell that this function does not invoke any noreturn function?". A different question could tackle the optimization issue around undefined behavior near division by zero, where one branch is optimized out, which is unrelated to "moving a trapping instruction in front of a function call". The issue is that the function call was never made, because compiler assumed arg2!=0. One would need sparc to check.

Comment: @KamilCuk The issue is related. If I understand what happened back then correctly, the compiler thought that a division that wouldoccur ''after'' a function call would necessarily occur, and thus that the divisor should not be 0 because otherwise there would be undefined behavior. This seems to me erroneous, since the compiler should not assume a function returns normally. Then I wondered how one would tell a compiler "yes this function always returns normally".

Comment: You have to tell the compiler that `ereport()` will _not_ return, in which case the program will exit on `arg2 == 0` and undefined behavior will never be possibly reached. I do not understand `yes this function always returns normally` - which function from the postgres thread would you mark with it?

Comment: @KamilCuk The bugfix was for them to tell the compiler that `ereport` never returns. However, this seems to me like working around a bug in gcc. Gcc, according to my understanding of the standard, should never have assumed `ereport` returned. And then I wondered: if a compiler cannot make such an assumption, maybe we could inform it that it is allowed to?

Comment: About "bad pointer due to an incorrect value of `i`": AFAIK, if the pointer is "bad", this is undefined behavior at the time of the pointer computation (no need for an access — remember memory segmentation), thus before `f()` is called; see 6.5.6p8 in ISO C17. Instead, you can just say `i = 10`: the pointer is valid (one past the last element of the array object), but the access is forbidden.

Comment: @vinc17 My bad you are of course correct, though one has the case where it is legal to compute a pointer just past the end of an array, bur not access it. I changed the example accordingly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For GCC: no, such attribute does not exist, not even internally in the compiler (as of GCC 13).

For Clang/LLVM: LLVM IR has the [`willreturn` function attribute](https://reviews.llvm.org/D62801), but Clang does not expose it for C and C++.